# Problems when installing UCB Schme

Tags: filesystems, scheme

I'm currently taking cs61a course. But, when Installing UCB Scheme, there's a problem that i don't understand.
I followed the instruction provided by [this website.](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~scheme/precompiled/MS-Windows/)

When typing the **"/usr/local/bin/setup-stk simply"**, there's meassage saying that

> cp: can not create regular file `/cygdrive/c/Users/没雨生/DeskTop': No
>   such file or directory.

I don't know what i've done wrong. Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: It's very likely that it can't handle Unicode pathnames. Try installing to a different location.

Comment: Thanks. How can i do that? I haven't known these kind of things yet. I just downloaded the file, double clicked it, and it's in that directory.

Comment: That doesn't work. Same problem.....

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for choosing UCB Scheme? Maybe a newer implementation would be easier to work with.

Comment: No, but the course(CS61A) is based on that.

Comment: @soegaard If he is following the SICP version as taught by Professor Harvey, then the course will include some extensions to the scheme language as detailed in Prof. Harvey's Simply Scheme book. It can be done using other Scheme REPLs but he is better off using the UCB Scheme distro since it includes these functions already.

Comment: @haziz You are probably right. DrRacket has a teaching language named "Simply Scheme" though. The professor ought to be able to help then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something worth trying: Create the missing directory:

```
 /cygdrive/c/Users/没雨生/DeskTop/
```

then run the script again.

My guess is that the script copies icons onto the Desktop - and
that the path of the Desktop folder has changed from the Windows used in 2008
to a modern version of Windows.